# How to use dom xpath in crawling?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I am new to dom xpath and I am trying to index a website as an exercise. I used to work with simple_html_dom so I wanted to try built in dom xpath to not depend on 3rd party libraries.

Url I am trying to scrape is:
`https://hackdesign.org/lessons`

Excerpt from my code:

```
$scriptDocument->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors(); 
$siteDOM = new DOMXPath($scriptDocument);

$base = $siteDOM->query('//div[@class="flex-auto prose"]');

if($base->length > 0) {
    foreach ($base as $title) {
        $title = $siteDOM->query('//a[@class="red"]');
        $hdtitlu = $title->nodeValue;
        $hdlink = 'https://hackdesign.org'.$title->getAttribute("href");
        echo $hdtitlu . '<br />';
        echo $hdlink . '<br />';        
    }
}
```

In my humble opinion this should have worked. I am starting from the base div that I want to get data from and then using a foreach, I am trying to get the title, link and description from the specific html tags.

Errors I get:

> Notice: Undefined property: DOMNodeList::$nodeValue in C:\UwAmp\www\test\index.php on line 31
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getAttribute() in C:\UwAmp\www\test\index.php on line 32
>
> Error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getAttribute() in C:\UwAmp\www\test\index.php on line 32

Line 31 is: `$hdtitlu = $title->nodeValue;`

Line 32 is: `$hdlink = 'https://hackdesign.org'.$title->getAttribute("href");`

Can you point me into the right direction ?!

Thank you,

Cristian

Comment: `DOMXPath::query()` returns a `DOMNodeList`, not a single node

Comment: In fact, why do you even have `$title = $siteDOM->query('//a[@class="red"]');`? `$title` is already defined by the `foreach` loop. Did you mean to include that line at all?

Comment: I was about to ask the same question that you posted. so deleted my comment.

Comment: I thought that I go from a base url and then I extract again what I need from the page. I will re-visit the code this afternoon and let you know the result. Thanks